# Is it normal to have 10k changes when runing npx create-react-app on my git interface on Vs code?

Tags: create-react-app, npx

Git after I pushed the npx create react app i have 12 000 changes is that normal to have or should be less changes?

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is normal.These changes come from your node modules files.if you want to disables these changes you can create gitignore file and add to node modules inside it.Thanks!

Comment: It's the `node_modules` file and the `package-lock.json` file that typically produce a load of changes. Although you want to gitignore `node_modules` you should keep your `package-lock.json`.